# Monitoring a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a multi-thread application (using C#) where the job of each thread is to insert some data into database. As soon the thread completes its job of inserting data into database it becomes free (i.e. ready to insert another data into database). All the threads are reading data from a queue.

The problem is, how to monitor which thread has completed its current job and ready to take second job? Whether we can use C# task instead of thread and how?

Please note every thread is inserting data to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, how to monitor which thread has completed its current job and 
>   ready to take second job?

Why would you do that? Threads created are looping until there is no data. If there is no thread (or less than wanted) and data arrives, start a new thread/task. Actually uses tasks. There is no need to monitor them. This would be ridiculously inefficient.

> Whether we can use C# task instead of thread and how?

Yes, and it is as simple as "look up how to start a task, which google has an answer for". That said, your architecture likely needs adjustment - doing too many things in parallel will only waste memory, rather limit the number of active threads/tasks to a specific number.

Comment: I have 10k  data in the queue and have limited number of thread (say 10 threads). How can I process all the data efficiently and insert them into database?

Suppose a thread is taking 2 sec to insert one data into database then 10k data will be inserted in 20k seconds (too much time) I do not want this. that's why I've created 10 threads.

Comment: By NOT doing it one by one. Start with "you have very little data" (I normally do bulk inserts with 60.000 rows PER CALL) and if your thread takes 2 seconds for one data - then fire the programmer.

Comment: How to perform bulk insert with 60 rows per call?

Comment: 60 rows per sinsert? Basic SQL? You do know you can insert more than one row with one INSERT statement? This is beginner SQL, same day as basic insert. Seriously. And then for a LOT of rows there is always SqlBulkCopy. I never said 60. I said 60.000.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use only Task not "Task in Thread".
Tasks are more flexible and already implemented robustly. In your case you can create an Task[] (with 10 Tasks if you want) and to know if the task has completed his work you can check the Task.Result value if you have declared Task<\TResult> objects.

in this way you can have direct control of the processes during the asynchronous execution including exception handling.